# SSH from Virtualbox Guest to DynDNS address

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox

I have Windows 10 as host with a Manjaro installation as Guest on Virtualbox.
I have set a Debian server on another house with ssh installed. I have setup a dyndns on Debian's network so I can access it remotely.

For example..

From address 12.34.56.78 I ssh to foo.dyndns.org:1234. This port redirects me to 192.168.1.5:22 always as this is my Debian machine and the connection is established. I am able to do this from Windows 10 as well as my android and any other device in 12.34.56.78 or by 3G.

But..

When I try to do this

```
$ ssh foo.dyndns.org:1234
```

from the Manjaro Guest in Virtualbox I get the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname foo.dyndns.org:1234: Name or service not known
```

So I did ifconfig and I saw my inet address was 10.0.2.15. I changed virtualbox's network adapter from NAT to Bridged so I can get a lan ip and I got the host's ip, 192.168.2.4. So I gave it another try and still didn't work.

Also, if i try to connect from vm to server while I'm in the same network

```
$ ssh user@192.168.2.5:22
```

it works. In this case virtualbox's network adapter was NAT.

This command works if I try from my android (connectbot).

I can connect the same way from PuTTY from Windows.

So my questions are:

- Can it be done?
- If so, how? (and why?)
- Can a VBox Guest get lan ip that's not the same as the host's?

Is there any more information I should provide?

I have searched for a couple of days in  here and on google and all I found where solutions on how someone can ssh INTO a vm. No one (from what I saw) asked the opposite.

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly how you're running ssh when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking manual page for [`ssh`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1?query=ssh&sec=1) reveals the format of command-line options:

```
ssh [...] [-p port] [...] [user@]hostnamessh
```

This simply describes, that you need to change

```
ssh foo.dyndns.org:1234
```

to

```
ssh -p 1234 foo.dyndns.org
```

if the domain resolves correctly to the ip address.

Comment: Yes, you're right. For some reason i thought [ip]:[port] was the right syntax for this. I read the manual but not carefully enough. Thanks.